# jQuery custom plugin not working as recommended by docs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pulling in jQuery, however the method the [docs](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation) recommends doesn't seem to be working, when wrapping the plugin with:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.tabs = function(options) {
        return $(this).css({color: red});
    }; 
}(jQuery)); 

$(document).ready(function(e) {   
    $('.some').tabs();
});
```

So applying a span with the `test` class should make this red. However, this doesn't work, but it does if I wrap it within the ready clause:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.fn.test = function(options) {
        return $(this).css({color: 'red'});
    };

    $('.test').test();
});
```

So this works.

Why does it not work when wrapping it in the first part?

I'm also pulling in (concatenated and minified) RivetsJS and Chart.JS.

Answer (score 1):

[As per every example in the docs](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), you're missing `(jQuery)` at the end....

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.test = function(options) {
        return $(this).css({color: 'red'});
    }; 
}( jQuery )); // <- this here
```

*Edit:  then you fixed the code in the question.*

---

Your top function is different than your bottom function.  The `"red"` was missing quotes and being interpreted as a variable (syntax error).

Otherwise, seems to be working...

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/wzvugpku/**

Comment: Oh, sorry... I did have that there, same issue.

Comment: @Alias, You seem to be mixing up two different functions.  In the top function `red` is missing quotes so it's being interpreted as a variable.